# How to show different dropdowns by choice

Tags: javascript

I want to show different dropboxes to user by its own choice.

example;

Dropbox1;

1-> Apple
2-> Bluberry

when user choose choice 1 it`ll show

1a -> Apple Juice
1b -> Apple

when user choose choice 2 it`ll show

2a -> Blueberry Juice
2b -> Blueberry

Comment: How cleanly you do this depends entirely on how many tiers there are and if it is a uniform number in all cases, and how you are binding the data to the lists (is it done programatically or is it static on the page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have to create such a thing, I'll create a multidimensional array. For example:
[
 ["Blueberry", "Pie"],
 ["Apple", "Pie"],
 ["Lemon", "Pie"]
]

Then in the first dropdown I set an onchange action to a function that checks which ID is selected, if for example ID 1 is selected, I'll get the array at index 1, in this example being ["Apple", "Pie"].

Then I'll empty the second dropdown and loop through the array to generate new options and place them in the body of the second dropdown.

Comment: Idk what you mean but I want to put 3 dropboxes like this and show only first one and once you choose what you want on first one I`ll show 2nd or 3rd do you know what I mean ?  

<select name="select" id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>

Comment: Ah, that's even simpler. Make sure the second and third dropdown have the style "display:none;". Then set an onchange on the first one and take the value of the selected option. If it's 0, set the style of the second dropdown on "display:inline;", if it's 1, do the same thing but on the third dropdown. You can change the style with Javascript like: document.getElementById("dropdownId").style = "display:inline";

Comment: I dont know how javascript works this is all I can do, can you please help me
`<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("dropdownId").style = "display:inline";
</script>
<select name="1st" onchange="">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<select name="1st" id="first">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<select name="1st" id="second">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>`

Comment: Thank you very much ! :) I dont know anything about javascript so thats why I asked you thanks againn !! ( =